# PostForm.js:36 POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am developing my college project but the post method does not work. I am using the native fetch method to post and MongoDB as a database.

I had tried Axios as well but I got the same error.

PostForm.js:36 POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

server.js
[backend code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzbPb.png)

PostForm.jsx
[PostForm code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5bNC.png)

please anyone tell me what is the mistake I have made.

Answer (score 0):

add `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"` in your React Project's `package.json` file , and restart your project

then in fetch method , url will `/`

```
fetch('/',{method:POST,...})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. after adding proxy I got two new errors. 1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large) 2.PostForm.js:37 POST http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_ABORTED 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)